# Is there a tabulated reference for CO$_2$ reactions showing entropy and free energy?

Tags: energy, entropy, resource-recommendations, climate-science, data

With all the climate change attention I am hoping to find a CO$_2$ reference that can help me find a $\text{CO}_2$ reaction with $\Delta \text{S}^{\circ}$ less than zero, and ideally $\Delta \text{G}^{\circ}$ also less than zero, but heating is OK. The sought-after reaction is either spontaneous or can be made so, and endothermic. I would imagine such a reaction would be highly sought and so hopefully good reference data has been published.

Comment: What would you use those data for? Also, $\Delta \text{G}^{\circ}<0$ is the case of most ('spontaneous') reactions.

Comment: Exploring CO2 as a refrigerant.

Comment: By 'reaction' do you mean *chemical reaction*?

Comment: I do mean chemical reaction.

Comment: CO2 really isn't reactive at all.

Comment: I’ve found several online, such as $CO_2 + H_2O \leftrightarrow  H_2CO_3$ (carbonic acid), and $\text{2LiOH} + CO_2 \rightarrow \text{Li}_2\text{CO}_3 + \text{H}_2\text{O}$. I can’t really search every individual compound and reaction like this however.

Comment: $CO_2 + H_2O \leftrightarrow  H_2CO_3$: that equilibrium leans VERY MUCH to the left.

Comment: But luckily for Coke, not always.

Comment: Nope. Fizzy drinks PROVE my point. If the equilibrium was predominantly to the right you wouldn't need pressurisation. The reaction with LiOH BTW also happen (and better) with the Na, K, Rb and Cs equivalents.

Comment: Also maybe of interest: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/ceat.201300603 CO2 and TEA.